# How to find out if there is a .NET Interface defined by Microsoft for an existing Microsoft COM Interface

Tags: .net, winforms, com, mfc, ole

For example, IWebBrowser2 is basically a COM interface originally made for IE. But the same interface is defined in .NET in Microsoft.ShDocVw.dll which can be directly used in a .NET program. For types like IUnknown, IInternetSecurityManager, IObjectSafety, IObjectWithSite etc, is there an assembly that exports .NET interfaces. I don't want to redefine the existing interfaces in my program. If I do, they may cause conflicts in future.

So, the question is, which Microsoft's .NET assemblies define these COM interfaces?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that any COM object that is properly registered is available under .NET ...

Comment: MSDN .NET function reference doesn't seem to have a .NET version of IUnknown.

Comment: It's not actually possible to define IUnknown in .NET.  Every interface you do define in .NET derives from either IUnknown or IDispatch based on whether you use [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)], [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)], or [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)].

Regarding your other query - I don't have an MSDN reference onhand, because I learned about this stuff years ago and it's not something you ever really need to refer back to.  I might find something and post it back here.

Answer (score 3):

> But the same interface is defined in .NET

It is **not** defined in .NET.  You got it by adding a reference to shdocvw.dll.  Visual Studio read the type library that's embedded in that DLL and generated the interop library from it.  Same thing that Tlbimp.exe does.  This is how COM interop works at the basic level.

There are *some* COM interface types already declared in .NET framework assemblies, most of them in the System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes namespace.  Very basic ones that .NET itself needed to get stuff done.  They are documented in MSDN so it doesn't take but a quick MSDN search to find them back.  And there's a bunch of them that are *internal*, just there to make a .NET wrapper class work, you could only ever find them back with the Reference Source or a decompiler.  Not otherwise useful beyond copy/paste.

Declaring COM interface types yourself is a perilous adventure and should always be avoided.  Small mistakes cause very nasty and hard to diagnose runtime errors.  Or no errors, the worst kind.  Always favor importing a type library when you have one, like you did with shdocvw.dll.  Type libraries were designed to avoid mistakes.  If you don't have a type library then googling code is the next best alternative.  And asking about it at SO of course.

Comment: I can open the SHDocVW.dll in ILDasm.exe which only shows the .NET IL. Does this mean, ILDasm is reading the type library exports from the SHDocVW.dll and generates an IL code?

Comment: That's not possible, c:\windows\system32\shdocvw.dll is a pure unmanaged DLL.  Ildasm.exe will complain that it doesn't have a valid CLR header.  You opened interop.shdocvw.dll, the interop library that was auto-generated from the type library.  And there's no code, only declarations.  The exact same declarations as present in the type library, but converted to the .NET metadata format.

Comment: So, which native library defines IUnknown interfaces?

Comment: This is a potentially never-ending comment trail.  You'll need to click the Ask Question button to ask new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Most consumers of COM interfaces, including in Microsoft code, define their own private definitions of those interfaces.  Since they are private, you could not use them even if you wanted to.  As long as you are not implementing the interfaces yourself, then it is impossible for this to ever cause any conflicts or problems.  If you are implementing a COM interface yourself, and you expect that you will be called from .NET code, then and only then do you need to use the same definition of the interface that the caller is using.

Comment: Is there a MSDN blog which talks on this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712(v=vs.71).aspx is probably a good place to start

Comment: See also: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/42590 if you're using VS2010 or 2012